# postgresql posix regexp

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix

I have the following rows of data:

> login;visit_homepage;buy
>
> register;login;buy;visit_homepage

I want to match all rows that have login event followed by buy event. There might be some other events between the login and buy events. Buy can be last event and login can be first event. I need exact match of login and buy not wildcard.

I have tried this:

`SELECT * FROM events WHERE events_list ~ 'login;.*buy;?.*$';`

but i think it does not cover all cases.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: include what you have tried

Comment: I have tried this:

SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE events_list ~ 'login;.*buy;?.*$';

Comment: include that  in the question... :)

Comment: should it select both the rows..?

Comment: yes, it should select both rows

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

This regex should match the rows:

```
\mlogin\M.*?\mbuy\M
```

It searches the word `login` followed later by `buy`.

- `\m` matches the beginning of a word
- `\M` matches the end of a word

Usage of the boundaries prevent matching `login` or `buy` that is composing a word (ex. `foologin`).

More info on these POSIX escapes in PostgreSQL [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE).

Comment: better than mine to avoid `foologin` cases. One more good practice learnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex to select both the rows

`login;.*buy.*$` or `login.*buy.*$`

you can check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/7q5Hkz/2)

Or you can simplify it even more by using `login.*buy`

Comment: it will not work correctly because .* will match anything before and after buy.

Comment: **I want to match all rows that have login event followed by buy event.**. that  is your requirement. my answer matches all rows containing event list having `login` followed by `buy`. i dont get where it is going wrong.. please provide more test cases on input output and the match you need